# HashMap in java cannot hash MyObject

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

I have defined a simple private class named **SetOb** which contains an **int** and a **Set** data structure. I have a HashMap in the 'main' method with **SetOb** as Key and Integer as value. Now as you can see in the main method, when I feed the HashMap with a **SetOb** instance and then look for an instance with exactly the same value, it returns 'null'. This has happened with me quite a few times before when I use my own defined data structures like **SetOb** as Key in HashMap. Can someone please point me what am I missing ?
Please note that in the constructor of SetOb class, I copy the Set passed as argument.

```
public class Solution {

    public static Solution sample = new Solution();
    private class SetOb {
        public int last;
        public Set<Integer> st;
        public SetOb(int l , Set<Integer> si ){
            last = l;
            st = new HashSet<Integer>(si);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<SetOb, Integer> m = new HashMap< SetOb, Integer>();
        Set<Integer> a = new HashSet<Integer>();

        for(int i =0; i<10; i++){
            a.add(i);
        }
        SetOb x = sample.new SetOb(100, a);
        SetOb y = sample.new SetOb(100, a);
        m.put(x,500);
        Integer val = m.get(y);
        if(val!= null) System.out.println("Success: " + val);
        else System.out.println("Failure");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `x` and `y` **are not the same object instances** hence contains is not able to match `y` against `x`, which ends up not finding the matching key/value in the Map.

If you want the match to succeed, please implement(override) `hasCode` & `equals` method in `SetOb` which will compare the field values.

Sample methods(Eclipse generated) as below:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + last;
    result = prime * result + ((st == null) ? 0 : st.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    SetOb other = (SetOb) obj;
    if (last != other.last)
        return false;
    if (st == null) {
        if (other.st != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!st.equals(other.st))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`SetOb` needs to override the `hashCode()` and thus the `equals()` methods.

Hash-based collections use these methods to store (`hashCode()`) and retrieve (`hashCode()`) and `equals()`) your objects.

Answer (score 2):

The default implementation of `hashCode` uses *object identity* to determine the hash code. You will need to implement `hashCode` (and `equals`) in your private class if you want *value identity*. For instance:

```
private class SetOb {
    public int last;
    public Set<Integer> st;
    public SetOb(int l , Set<Integer> si ){
        last = l;
        st = new HashSet<Integer>(si);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other.class == SetOb.class) {
            SetOb otherSetOb = (SetOb) other;
            return otherSetOb.last == last && otherSetOb.st.equals(st);
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 37 * last + st.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you said _object_ identity, did you mean _identity by reference_ ? Thanks for the info.

Comment: @DeepakGarg - Exactly. With object identity, two distinct objects are never considered equal (even though they could, _in theory_ have the same hash code). Thus, one cannot substitute for the other as the key to a hash table lookup.